# Why do I get the "bad bind variable" error when trying to create an INSTEAD OF trigger in PL/SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have these 4 tables:

```
Suppliers( id_sup, name, city)

Products (id_prod, name, city)

Companies (id_co, name, city)

Deliveries (id_sup, id_prod, id_co)
```

I created a view for Deliveries called "v_deliveries" and I want to create an instead of trigger so that if someone tries inserting data in the view, it will actually add it to the Deliveries table. This is what i've tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_deliv_trigg
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON v_deliveries FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Deliveries (id_sup, id_prod, id_co)
VALUES (:NEW.id_sup, :NEW.id_prod, :NEW.id_co);
End;
```

Answer (score 0):

Which database do you really use? Because, as for Oracle, it works OK:

```
SQL> create table deliveries (id_sup number, id_prod number, id_co number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace view v_deliveries as select * From deliveries;

View created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_deliv_trigg
  2  INSTEAD OF INSERT ON v_deliveries FOR EACH ROW
  3  BEGIN
  4  INSERT INTO Deliveries (id_sup, id_prod, id_co)
  5  VALUES (:NEW.id_sup, :NEW.id_prod, :NEW.id_co);
  6  End;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you! I found where my error was. My view had different column names